Tabnavigation on hidden elements – mmenu.js v5.7.8
Using the mmenu.js v5.7.8 (formerly known as jQuery mmenu) I have the following config:
$('#menu').mmenu({ 
      extensions: [ 'effect-slide-menu', 'shadow-page', 'shadow-panels', 'pagedim-black' ],
      keyboardNavigation: true,
      screenReader: true,
      iconPanels: true,
      navbar:{
         title : 'Meny'
      },

      navbars:[
         {
            position : 'top',
            content : [
               'prev',
               'title',
               'close'
            ]
         }
      ],

      offCanvas: {
         position  : "right"
      }
   });

When navigating through the menu by keyboard (tab-navigation) I get an extra tab on a hidden item. As per checking it is the following item in the initial state of the menu:
<a href="#mm-1" class="mm-subblocker" tabindex="0"></a>
Here is the DOM structure of the menu with the a tag above :
`

<div class="mm-navbar mm-navbar-top mm-navbar-top-1 mm-navbar-size-1 mm-hasbtns">
    <a class="mm-prev mm-btn mm-hidden" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0"><span class="mm-sronly">Close submenu
            ()</span></a>
    <a class="mm-title">Meny</a>
    <a class="mm-close mm-btn" href="#mm-0" tabindex="0">
        <span class="mm-sronly">Stäng meny</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="mm-panels">
    <div class="mm-panel mm-opened mm-current mm-iconpanel-0" id="mm-1">
        
        <a href="#mm-1" class="mm-subblocker" tabindex="0"></a>

        <div class="mm-navbar mm-hidden"><a class="mm-title">Meny</a></div><ul class="mm-listview">

        <ul class="mm-listview">
            <li class="notSelected">
                <a href="/" tabindex="0" class="">Startsidan</a>

            </li>
            <li class="notSelected">
                <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-1" data-target="#mm-1" aria-owns="mm-1" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mm-sronly">Open submenu (Skola och förskola)</span></a>
                        <a href="/skola-och-forskola"tabindex="0">Skola och förskola</a>
            </li>
            ....
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
<input class="mm-tabend" tabindex="0" type="text"> 

    `
I don't get why this item is here to begin with and if there is any option that makes this happen. Would appreciate any suggestion or help in order to fix this issue.
What happened:

Opened the menu (either by click or keybaord)
Started to navigate with keyboard
After tabbing to "x" close button I get 2 extra tabs on invisible items before getting to the first menu item. (It should have got to the first item after the close button)


To interact and see the live version check this address: https://www.botkyrka.se/

I don't think there's a built-in option for this in the mmenu settings. I'd recommend tweaking the DOM a bit with jQuery to change the tabindex from 0 to -1 for the elements you want to skip when tabbing. For instance, you can set the tabindex of all .mm-subblocker elements to -1 when the open event is triggered like this:
$(".mm-subblocker[tabindex='0']").attr("tabindex", "-1");

